# Angular JS controller not working when enclosed with $(function () {});

Tags: angularjs

When I enclose the controller code within the `$(function () {});` method, it stopped working. Please find the sample code as mentioned bleow:

**Contacts.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Contacts</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="ContactsController">
        <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="newcontact.name" />
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="newcontact.email" />
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="newcontact.phone" />
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" ng-model="newcontact.id" />
            <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveContact()" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="edit(contact.id)">edit</a>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="delete(contact.id)">delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uid = 1;
    $(function () {
        function ContactsController($scope) {
            $scope.contacts = [
                { id: 0, 'name': 'Viral', 'email': 'hello@gmail.com', 'phone': '123-2343-44' }
            ];


        }
    });
</script>
```

If I remove the `$(function () {});` method then it starts to work and give the required output.
Can anyone help me to know the details about the issue.

Comment: Why do you need this `$(function () {});` ?

Comment: $(function () {}); I need to in order to execute the ContactController code once the entire DOM is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping your controller with `$(function () { });` you are creating a closure scope an thus `ContactsController` is not visible outside that scope, your controller instead should have a root (window) scope in order to be accessible! Yo have to remove your closure or define your controller as `window.ContactsController = function(){}` or simply `ContactsController = function(){}` in order to make it "public"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. It helped me a lot to know the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the controller is defined in the closure it is no logger available to the outer environment in order to make this code work you can add the following inside the closure

```
$(function () {

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('ContactsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     // your code
    }]);

});
```

This way the code will not only be modular and also the global scope / public scope will not be polluted